# Stuck at Erasing

Tags: unbricking, bootloader, bootloader-lock, nexus-6, motorola-nexus-6

I tried doing a factory reset on my Nexus 6 and the device got stuck in "Erasing". All I am able to do now is enter fastboot flash mode but none of the options work as the boot loader is locked.

Tried flashing with a factory image from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/images#shamu) but that too failed because the device is locked.

```
--------------------------------------------
Bootloader Version...: moto-apq8084-72.01
Baseband Version.....: D4.01-9625-05.42+FSG-9625-02.113
Serial Number........: ZX1G524DKM
--------------------------------------------
checking product...
OKAY [  0.002s]
checking version-bootloader...
OKAY [  0.002s]
checking version-baseband...
OKAY [  0.003s]
sending 'boot' (8485 KB)...
OKAY [  0.268s]
writing 'boot'...
(bootloader) Not allowed in LOCKED state!
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 0.287s
```

Comment: Screwed device with locked bootloader basically means sending for repair.

Comment: Try unlocking the bootloader if your rooted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I left it out on charge overnight and it resolved itself. When I did the initial reset, the battery was on full charge so it never occurred to me that it could be a problem.